# Start service from activity, 2 apps

Tags: android, android-service

I have two applications. One app has the Activity and another one is a background service.
how do i start the service from the activity?

i tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent () ;
intent.setClassName("com.example.mySerive","com.example.mySerive.service") ;
this.startService(intent);
```

Comment: What was the outcome of your try? Did it produced errors?

Answer (score 1):

First you should declare your service on AndroidManifest of your second App:

Like activities (and other components), you must declare all services in your application's manifest file.

To declare your service, add a  element as a child of the  element. For example:

```
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
      ...
  </application>
```

If you plan on using your service only locally (other applications do not use it), then you don't need to (and should not) supply any intent filters. Without any intent filters, you must start the service using an intent that explicitly names the service class. More information about starting a service is discussed below.

As you want to use on external application you must define a IntentFilter :

```
<service android:name=".ExampleService" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="br.com.androidzin.MyService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

After that, you can start your service on your external app on this way:

```
  Intent intent=new Intent("br.com.androidzin.MyService");  
  this.startService(intent);
```